# Conditional regex in Ruby

Tags: regex, ruby

I've got the following string:

```
'USD 100'
```

Based on [this post](https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/using-conditionals-inside-ruby-regular-expressions/) I'm trying to capture `100` if `USD` is contained in the string **or** the individual (currency) characters if `USD` is not contained in the string.

For example:

```rb
'USD 100' # => '100'
'YEN 300' # => ['Y', 'E', 'N']
```

So far I've got up to this but it's not working:

https://rubular.com/r/cK8Hn2mzrheHXZ

Interestingly if I place the `USD` after the amount it seems to work. Ideally I'd like to have the same behaviour regardless of the position of the currency characters.

Comment: The pattern `\b(?:USD (\d+)|(?!USD\b)(\w+) \d+)\b` gets close, except that it captures the entire non USD currency symbol, rather than capturing each letter in a separate capture group.  To capture each letter, you might need some tricks in Ruby.

Comment: `YEN` would also do the trick just fine. It doesn't have to be each and every letter in an array. I'm wondering though; Why doesn't the look ahead work?

Comment: Do you mean like this? `(?:(USD) )?(?(1)(\d+)|([a-zA-Z]))`  https://rubular.com/r/quQSSLzsj0Om1q  Then check for group 2 or group 3

Comment: I explained the problem in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62729709/3832970). Basically, only strings containing `USD` will match because the positive lookahead requires it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex `(?=.*(USD))(?(1)\d+|[a-zA-Z])` does not work because

- `(?=.*(USD))` - a positive lookahead, triggered at every location inside a string (if `scan` is used) that matches `USD` substring after any 0 or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible (it means, there will only be a match if there is `USD` somewhere on a line)
- `(?(1)\d+|[a-zA-Z])` - a conditional construct that matches 1+ digits if Group 1 matched (if there is `USD`), or, an ASCII letter will be tried. **However**, the second alternative pattern will *never* be tried, because you required `USD` to be present in the string for a match to occur.

Look at the `USD 100` [regex debugger](https://regex101.com/r/HNuu4E/1/debugger), it shows exactly what happens when the `(?=.*(USD))(?(1)\d+|[a-zA-Z])` regex tries to find a match:

- Step 1 to 22: The lookahead pattern is tried first. The point here is that the match will fail immediately if the positive lookahead pattern does not find a match. In this case, `USD` is found at the start  of the string (since the first time the pattern is tried, the regex index is at the string start position). The lookahead found a match.
- Step 23-25: since a lookahead is a non-consuming pattern, the regex index is still at the string start position. The lookahead says "go-ahead", and the conditional construct is entered. `(?(1)` condition is met, Group 1, `USD`, was matched. So, the first, *`then`*, part is triggered. `\d+` does not find any digits, since there is `U` letter at the start.  **The regex match fails at the string start position**, but there are more positions in the string to test since there is no `\A` nor `^` anchor that would only let a match to occur if the match is found at the start of the string/line.
- Step 26: The regex engine index is advanced one char to the right, now, it is right before the letter `S`.
- Step 27-40: The regex engine wants to find 0+ chars and then `USD` immediately to the right of the current location, but fails (`U` is already "behind" the index).
- Then, the execution is just the same as described above: the regex fails to match `USD` anywhere to the right of the current location and eventually fails.

If the `USD` is somewhere to the right of `100`, then you'd [get a match](https://regex101.com/r/HNuu4E/2).

So, the **lookahead does not set any search range, it simply allows matching the rest of the patterns (if its pattern matches) or not (if its pattern is not found)**.

You may use

```
.scan(/^USD.*?\K(\d+)|([a-zA-Z])/).flatten.compact
```

**Pattern details**

- `^USD.*?\K(\d+)` - either `USD` at the start of the string, then any 0 or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible, and then the text matched is dropped and 1+ digits are captured into Group 1
- `|` - or
- `([a-zA-Z])` - any ASCII letter captured into Group 2.

See [Ruby demo](https://rextester.com/QKSN58186):

```
p "USD 100".scan(/^USD.*?\K(\d+)|([a-zA-Z])/).flatten.compact
# => ["100"]
p "YEN 100".scan(/^USD.*?\K(\d+)|([a-zA-Z])/).flatten.compact
# => ["Y", "E", "N"]
```

Comment: You couldn't wait for me to update it :-) That pattern is almost the same principle with an anchor and a non greedy quantifier ++

Comment: @Thefourthbird Sorry, I thought the code would be the differentiator.

Comment: No no, I mean it in a positive way, my Ruby knowledge is very little and this is a complete answer.

Comment: Great answer! The new regex seems to work!However could you please explain a bit more why my solution does not? I do have ‘USD’ in my string (‘USD 100’) thus the conditional should evaluate ‘\d+’ (‘100’) but it didn’t.  Also whats this second alternative pattern that you mentioned..?

Comment: @kstratis See [your regex debugger](https://regex101.com/r/HNuu4E/1/debugger) step by step. Here is the [pattern demo](https://regex101.com/r/HNuu4E/1/). The point is that the positive lookahead requires the `USD` to be after the digits. A conditional construct is a group with two alternatives, your `(?(1)\d+|[a-zA-Z])` has  `\d+` and `[a-zA-Z]`.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew. I just posted an answer below myself explaining just that. It's exactly what I eventually concluded myself too. I just phrased in a way which I think is a bit easier to grasp since I struggled a bit myself to understand what you were suggesting in the first place.

Comment: @kstratis I added the full explanation with a link to the regex debugger.

Answer (score 3):

*Anatomy of your pattern*

```
(?=.*(USD))(?(1)\d+|[a-zA-Z])
|    |     | |  |   |_______
|    |     | |  |   Else match a single char a-zA-Z
|    |     | |  |   
|    |     | |  |__
|    |     | |  If group 1 exists, match 1+ digits
|    |     | |
|    |     | |__
|    |     | Test for group 1
|    |     |_________________
|    |     If Clause
|    |___
|    Capture group 1
|__________
Positive lookahead
```

*About the pattern you tried*

> The positive lookahead is not anchored and will be tried on each position. It will continue the match if it returns true, else the match stops and the engine will move to the next position.

*Why does the pattern not match?*

On the first position the lookahead is true as it can find USD on the right.
It tries to match 1+ digits, but the first char is `U` which it can not match.

```
USD 100
⎸
First position
```

From the second position till the end, the lookahead is false because it can not find USD on the right.

```
USD 100
 ⎸
Second position
```

- Eventually, the if clause is only tried once, where it could not match 1+ digits. The else clause is never tried and overall there is no match.
- For the `YEN 300` part, the if clause is never tried as the lookahead will never find USD at the right and overall there is no match.

Interesting resources about conditionals can be for example found at [rexegg.com](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-conditionals.html#check_numgroup) and [regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html)

---

If you want the separate matches, you might use:

```
\bUSD \K\d+|[A-Z](?=[A-Z]* \d+\b)
```

**Explanation**

- `\bUSD`  Match USD and a space
- `\K\d+` Forget what is matched using `\K` and match 1+ digits
- `|` Or
- `[A-Z]` Match a char A-Z
- `(?=[A-Z]* \d+\b)` Assert what is on the right is optional chars A-Z and 1+ digits

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gnVxhT/1)

Or using capturing groups:

```
\bUSD \K(\d+)|([A-Z])(?=[A-Z]* \d+\b)
```

[Regex demo](https://rubular.com/r/ROscFints3eS0l)

Comment: It looks like [OP wants an explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62728701/conditional-regex-in-ruby#comment110928798_62728701) of their regex (and why it does not work) more than a solution.

Comment: I can add it later, just left my machine.

Answer (score 1):

The following pattern seems to work:

```
\b(?:USD (\d+)|(?!USD\b)(\w+) \d+)\b
```

This works with caveat that it just has a single capture group for the non USD currency symbol.  One part of the regex might merit explanation:

```
(?!USD\b)(\w+)
```

This uses a negative lookahead to assert that the currency symbol is not USD.  If so, then it captures that currency symbol.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the information desired be extracted as follows.

```
R = /\b([A-Z]{3}) +(\d+)\b/
```

```
def doit(str)
  str.scan(R).each_with_object({}) do |(cc,val),h|
    h[cc] = (cc == 'USD') ? val : cc.split('')
  end
end
```

```
doit 'USD 100'
  #=> {"USD"=>"100"} 
doit 'YEN 300'
  #=> {"YEN"=>["Y", "E", "N"]} 
doit 'I had USD 6000 to spend'
  #=> {"USD"=>"6000"} 
doit 'I had YEN 25779 to spend'
  #=> {"YEN"=>["Y", "E", "N"]} 
doit 'I had USD 60 and CDN 80 to spend'
  #=> {"USD"=>"60", "CDN"=>["C", "D", "N"]} 
doit 'USD -100'
  #=> {} 
doit 'YENS 4000'
  #=> {}
```

[Regex demo](https://rubular.com/r/ULXgIShVYiX6wC)

Ruby's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
\b          : assert a word boundary
([A-Z]{3})  : match 3 uppercase letters in capture group 1
\ +         : match 1+ spaces
(\d+)       : match 3 digits in capture group 2
\b          : assert a word boundary
```

Answer (score -1):

**TLDR;**

An excellent [working solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62729709/178728) can be found in [Wiktor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62729709/178728)'s answer and the rest of the posts.

**Long answer:**

Since I wasn't perfectly satisfied with [Wiktor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62729709/178728)'s explanation of why [my solution](https://rubular.com/r/cK8Hn2mzrheHXZ) wasn't working, I decided to dig into it a bit more myself and this is my take on it:

Given the string `USD 100`, the following regex

```
(?=.*(USD))(?(1)\d+|[a-zA-Z])
```

**simply won't work**. The juice of this whole thing is to figure out **why**.
It turns out that using a lookahead (`?=.*(USD)`) with a capture group, implicitly suggests that **the position** of `USD` (if any is found) is followed by some pattern (defined inside the conditional (`(?(1)\d+|[a-zA-Z])`) which in this case yields nothing since there's nothing before `USD`.

If we break it down in steps here's an outline of what -I think- is happening:

1. The pointer is set at the very beginning. The lookahead (`?=.*(USD)`) is parsed and executed.
2. `USD` is found but since the expression is a lookahead the pointer remains at the beginning of the string and is not consumed.
3. The conditional (`(?(1)\d+|[a-zA-Z])`) is parsed and executed.
4. Group `1` is set (since `USD` has been found) **however** `\d+` fails since the pointer  searches **from the beginning of the string** to the **beginning of the string** which turns out is the furthest point we can search when using a lookahead! After all that's exactly why it's called a lookahead: The searching has to happen across a range which stops just before this one starts.
5. Since no digits nor anything is found before `USD`, the regex returns no results. And as [Wiktor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62729709/178728) correctly pointed out:

> the second alternative pattern will never be tried, because you required USD to be present in the string for a match to occur.

which basically says that since `USD` is always present in the string, the system would never jump to the "else" statement even if something was eventually found before `USD`.

As a counter example if the same regex is tested on this string, it will work:

```
'YEN USD 100'
```

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: Your "*lookahead implicitly sets the "upper bound" of the regex "search range" pointer*" explanation is wrong. A "forward lookahead" is pleonasm, any lookahead is "forward looking", as the backwards looking lookaround is called a lookbehind. The lookahead is positive here, and asserts the position is followed with some pattern. In your case, it is `.*USD`, `USD` must appear after any 0 or more chars other than line break chars immediately to the right of the current location. When `USD` is after the digits, [there is a match](https://regex101.com/r/fWuSga/1).

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew. I corrected the wording just like you suggested. It should hopefully be correct now. I understand that we are essentially saying the exact same thing.

Comment: I truly believe your "*the pointer searches from the beginning of the string to the beginning of the string which turns out is the furthest point we can search when using a lookahead*" and "*The searching has to happen across a range which stops just before this one starts*" explanations are misleading. Lookaheads do not set the range. They are boolean "functions" that return either `true` or `false`, nothing else. You may say lookaheads set the left-/right-hand side context for a match. "Ranges" are better avoided as they are related to something different in regex.